# C++: stopping last increment in my Fizz Buzz program

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, increment

So as part of a coding challenge I tried to make a Fizz Buzz program in C++ without looking at the solution. For those of you who don't know, it should be a loop that replaces any number divisible by 3 with `Fizz`, any number divisible by 5 with `Buzz`, and any number divisible by both with `FizzBuzz`:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
6
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
```

I'm almost there with the code below, however, i'm a little annoyed that even though I want the loop to stop entirely at 100, the way i've set up the program means that an extra 1 gets added to `i` after the loop has ended. Is there a way of stopping my FizzBuzz program from going past 100?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i){

if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){
    cout << "FizzBuzz\n";
    i = i + 1;
}

if (i % 3 == 0){
  cout << "Fizz\n";
  i = i + 1;
}

if (i % 5 == 0){
  cout << "Buzz\n";
  i = i + 1;
}

cout << i << "\n";

}

}
```

Comment: If it's a *coding challenge*, and you're asking us for help completing it, doesn't that defeat the entire purpose of accepting the *challenge*? What's the point of a challenge when you're not doing things yourself?

Comment: The posted code doesn't match the output quoted above it, and it doesn't do what you describe anyway. `an extra 1 gets added to i after the loop has ended` There is no `i` after the loop has ended, since that variable only exists inside the loop.

Comment: you shouldn't be incrementing `i` inside the loop.  Use `else` statements

Comment: @KenWhite • Some people like to do 9x9 Sudoku with the answers.  Others like to do a 1x1 Sudoku.

Comment: @KenWhite: do you apply an all-or-nothing approach to everything you do? If that's the case then I feel kinda sorry for you. Some people sleep. @dxiv: actually it does, i cut and pasted the first 12 numbers of the output not to be too tedious. However, what i was confused about is why it always prints ```101``` even though the loop is supposed to end at 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed your code a little bit:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i)
    {
       if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
            cout << "FizzBuzz\n";
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            cout << "Fizz\n";
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << "Buzz\n";
        else
            cout << i << "\n";

    }

}
```

Every time you do `i = i + 1;`, it's kinda useless because your loop does that. Also, I put everything is an `if else` chain, instead of and `if if` chain. That way only on statement will execute at any giving time. Also changed the max to 101 instead of 100 since the for loop will stop at 101 and not print the result of 101.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks, it's nice to have this coding forum to clear things up in moments of frustration/confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, variables have a *lifetime*, called their scope, and after their lifetime expires they are deleted. The i that is defined in the loop declaration has the scope constrained by the closing brace "}" of the for loop. Due to this, the variable i does not exist *after* the loop, only during. However in the code you have provided, the problem is that you are incrementing i multiple times. In your for loop you increment i every time the body of the for loop is executed, but within that body you increment i when it is divisible by 5 or 3 or both or neither. You can remove all of the i = i + 1; statements and remove most of the bugs.

Comment: Wait... what does the scope of `i` have to do with things?

Comment: The question was regarding what happens to i after the loop is finished. Technically after the loop is finished there is no i since it has fallen out of scope.

Comment: But the only thing in the main function is the loop, there is no "after the loop"?